# Limiting Execution Time for a called CFC

Tags: coldfusion, timeout

We have a ColdFusion edit that checks MX records to soft validate email addresses. We get occasional long responses from the DNS servers and need to restrict how long we wait for a response before giving up.

The component called does the actual lookup. The code reproduced below is part of a larver validation script.

What I want to do is limit how long I will wait for the lookup component to run and then handle the error when it exceeds that time. This code appears correct to me, but it just blows right past the timeout (I have a "sleep" in the component to mimic a slow response.)

```
try {
    requesttimeout="10";
    MyNewArray[1] = right(MyEmail, RightChars);
    mycnt = new common.functions.mxLookup(MyNewArray);
    Caller.EmailReturnCode = iif(mycnt gt 0,'"0"','"2"');
}
catch ("coldfusion.runtime.RequestTimedOutException" a) {
    Caller.EmailReturnCode = "2";
}
catch (any e) {
    Caller.EmailReturnCode = "2";
}
```

Comment: I think you need the requesttimeout in the mxLookup function.

Comment: Reaching `requestTimeout` stops the whole (request) thread, that's not desirable. I can think of two ways: 1 Use a connection timeout in the lookup itself (depends on what you use to perform the lookup) or 2 Spawn a separate thread that does the lookup and has to finish within x seconds. There is [`cfthread`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-t/cfthread.html) with `action="run"` to spawn the lookup and `action="join"` to await the response (this one supports a timeout).

Comment: Thanks... Yes, that's the way to go. Do you want to add it as an "answer"?

Comment: There's a JAR you can use that performs email + optional MX validation much better (and caches results). It also honors DNS TTL. Sample CFML at https://gist.github.com/JamoCA/72cdcb77246ea0ee5820

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        thread action="run" name="doLookup" {
            variables.mycnt = new common.functions.mxLookup(MyNewArray);
        }
        thread action="join" name="doLookup" timeout="20000";
        if(doLookup.Status is "RUNNING"){
            thread action="terminate" name="doLookup";
            throw("MX Lookup of #MyEmail# timed out", "toException", "MX Lookup exceeded allowed time of 20 seconds at #timeFormat(now(),'HH:mm:sss')#");
        }
        Caller.EmailReturnCode = iif(mycnt gt 0,'"0"','"2"');
```

Thanks to Alex

This solution works perfectly.